# Why openlayers show wrong measures of line from ECW geoserver?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have loaded the following raster into geoserver and added measurement control.
The thing is that the measure gives me wrong result (it shows the car length is 49m)
Any idea what can cause this ?!

For the code , I used the generated code from "Preview Layer" in geoserver and just added the dynamic measure control to it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the **geodesic** property to **true** when you create the Measure control.

According to the [OpenLayers documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Measure-js.html) the **geodesic** property is used to:

> Calculate geodesic metrics instead of planar metrics.  This requires
>   that geometries can be transformed into Geographic/WGS84 (if that is
>   not already the map projection).

Comment: Tried that , I gives me now 77KM length for a car.

Comment: Then we need to know a bit more about your setup. What is the srs of your layer and can you show some code. In particular the code where you define the map with options, the layer and the measurement control. The generated code from "Preview Layer" in geoserver could be different depending on the verison of GeoServer.